# Representing word similarity between words from two lists in a homogeneous way in python

Tags: python, list, nlp, spacy, cosine-similarity

I am trying an NLP technique to see similarity between words from two lists.

The code is as below

```
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

Listalpha = ['Apple', 'Grapes', 'Mango', 'Fig','Orange']

ListBeta = ['Carrot', 'Mango', 'Tomato', 'Potato', 'Lemon']

list_n =" ".join(ListBeta)     
doc = nlp(list_n)   


list_str = " ".join(Listalpha)    
doc2 = nlp(list_str)

newlist = []

for token1 in doc:
    for token2 in doc2:
        newlist.append((token1.text, token2.text,token1.similarity(token2)))


words_most_similar = sorted(newlist, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
print(words_most_similar)
```

I get the following output

```
[('Mango', 'Mango', 1.0), ('Potato', 'Mango', 0.71168435), ('Lemon', 'Orange', 0.70560765), ('Carrot', 'Mango', 0.670182), ('Tomato', 'Mango', 0.6513121), ('Potato', 'Fig', 0.6306212), ('Tomato', 'Fig', 0.61672616), ('Carrot', 'Apple', 0.6077532), ('Lemon', 'Mango', 0.5978425), ('Mango', 'Fig', 0.5930651), ('Mango', 'Orange', 0.5529714), ('Potato', 'Apple', 0.5516073), ('Potato', 'Orange', 0.5486618), ('Lemon', 'Fig', 0.50294644), ('Mango', 'Apple', 0.48833746), ('Tomato', 'Orange', 0.44175738), ('Mango', 'Grapes', 0.42697987), ('Lemon', 'Apple', 0.42477235), ('Carrot', 'Fig', 0.3984716), ('Carrot', 'Grapes', 0.3944748), ('Potato', 'Grapes', 0.3860814), ('Tomato', 'Apple', 0.38342345), ('Carrot', 'Orange', 0.38251868), ('Tomato', 'Grapes', 0.3763761), ('Lemon', 'Grapes', 0.28998604)]
```

How do I get an output in the format as below

```
[('Mango','Mango',1.0),('Mango', 'Fig', 0.5930651), ('Mango', 'Orange', 0.5529714),('Mango', 'Apple', 0.48833746),('Mango', 'Grapes', 0.42697987),('Carrot', 'Mango', 0.670182),('Carrot', 'Apple', 0.6077532)....]
```

Basically I want the mapping of the form (word in ListBeta, word in Listalpha, cosine score) and it should be uniform and not at random as I have currently. Also it needs to be in descending order of cosine value as depicted above.

Comment: So you want a sort on first token, and than on score?

Comment: @Slam Yes, I want to sort on first token and on descending order. Basically the output should be like this `[('Mango','Mango',1.0),('Mango', 'Fig', 0.5930651), ('Mango', 'Orange', 0.5529714),('Mango', 'Apple', 0.48833746),('Mango', 'Grapes', 0.42697987),('Carrot', 'Mango', 0.670182),('Carrot', 'Apple', 0.6077532)....]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's indeed question of sorting results, you can use tuples as key result in `sorted`, i.e. your lambda could return tuple/list, and python will sort on it element-wise.

```
words_most_similar = sorted(newlist, key=lambda t: (t[0], -t[2]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but your solution give me output like this `[('Carrot', 'Orange', 0.38251868), ('Carrot', 'Grapes', 0.3944748), ('Carrot', 'Fig', 0.3984716), ('Carrot', 'Apple', 0.6077532), ('Carrot', 'Mango', 0.670182)]
[('Mango', 'Grapes', 0.42697987), ('Mango', 'Apple', 0.48833746), ('Mango', 'Orange', 0.5529714), ('Mango', 'Fig', 0.5930651), ('Mango', 'Mango', 1)]`  I want the output like `[('Mango','Mango',1.0),('Mango', 'Fig', 0.5930), ('Mango', 'Orange', 0.5529),('Mango', 'Apple', 0.48833),('Mango', 'Grapes', 0.42697987),('Carrot', 'Mango', 0.6701),('Carrot', 'Apple', 0.6077)`

Comment: Any reason it should start with `Mango` and not `Carrot`? It is alphabetically sorted.

Comment: sorry I missed that part. Yes you are right. It can be alphabetically sorted but the problem is it is not in descending order of cosine values. i.e ideally is should like `[('Carrot', 'Mango', 0.670182),('Carrot', 'Apple', 0.6077532),('Carrot', 'Fig', 0.3984716),('Carrot', 'Grapes', 0.3944748),('Carrot', 'Orange', 0.38251868)]` @Slam

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing minus sign in `lambda t: (t[0], -t[2])`? It's actually descending sort by similarity

Comment: yes you are right, my bad. I forgot to remove 'reverse= True' . Now it is working fine. Any suggestion on how to restrict the pairs to just top 3 by descending order? Like it should stop at (carrot, fig 0.39) `[('Carrot', 'Mango', 0.670182),('Carrot', 'Apple', 0.6077532),('Carrot', 'Fig', 0.3984716)`

Comment: I guess, It's a little bit out of scope. This is valid questions, try something out, if you'll have no luck — create new question with minimal reproduceable code and someone will help you ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I figured the restricted to 3 pairs part.